# How do I split a list of unquoted paths with embedded spaces into individual paths?

Tags: string, bash, shell, divide

I'm not good at bash shell scripting in Ubuntu, so I need your help.

The problem is...

We use Perforce for SCM.

I try to get directories from `//Development/` branches.

Until this time, everything was good.

But now I can't split branches by whitespace anymore, because of branches such as the following (note the embedded space):

`//Development/graphic/release/Unity Provider`

We need each branch on a separate line starting with `//Development`, but always I get the following result (note the unwanted line break):

```
//Development/graphic/release/Unity
Provider
```

How can I fix this?

Please help me.
Thank you.

Below is a sample one-line string:

```
//Development/graphic/release/CM //Development/graphic/release/GManager //Development/graphic/release/Notification //Development/graphic/release/Core //Development/graphic/release/Provider //Development/graphic/release/WH //Development/graphic/release/Accessory //Development/graphic/release/Unity Provider //Development/graphic/release/tipManager
```

And, I want to get a result string like below (each branch name on its own line):

```
//Development/graphic/release/CM 
//Development/graphic/release/GManager 
//Development/graphic/release/Notification 
//Development/graphic/release/Core 
//Development/graphic/release/Provider 
//Development/graphic/release/WH 
//Development/graphic/release/Accessory 
//Development/graphic/release/Unity Provider 
//Development/graphic/release/tipManager
```

**I also want to store the results in a list variable.**

E.g., `list[0]` should contain `//Development/graphic/release/CM`.

Comment: what's your expected output?

Comment: How are you determining the directories?  Can you not rename the directory to `Unity-Provider` to avoid the agony of spaces in the path name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that:

- you want to split your input string into individual paths based on substrings starting with `//[Development/]`, either at the start of the string, or, if inside, preceded by a single space.
- regardless of whether the strings between `//[Development/]` instances contain spaces or not.

```sh
str='//Development/graphic/release/CM //Development/graphic/release/GManager //Development/graphic/release/Notification //Development/graphic/release/Core //Development/graphic/release/Provider //Development/graphic/release/WH //Development/graphic/release/Accessory //Development/graphic/release/Unity Provider //Development/graphic/release/tipManager'    

echo "$str" | sed 's# \(//\)#\'$'\n''\1#g'
```

The above should work with any POSIX-compatible `sed` implementation.

To capture the output in a variable, using [command substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/CommandSubstitution):

```
result=$(echo "$str" | sed 's# \(//\)#\'$'\n''\1#g')
```

If you then want to process the result line by line:

```
while read -r path; do echo "$path"; done <<<"$result"
```

Explanation of the `sed` command:

- `#` was - arbitrarily - chosen as the delimiter for `sed`'s `s` (string substitution) command so as to make it easier to match `/` chars (customarily, `/` is used as the delimiter, which would necessitate `\`-escaping `/` instances in the regex and replacement string).
- `\(//\)` matches `//` if preceded by a space, i.e., inside the string.
- `\'$'\n''` effectively inserts a newline (`\n`) into the replacement string, using ANSI C quoting (required for OSX compatibility; on Linux, just `\n` would do).
- `\1` inserts the 1st (and only) capture group from the regex, i.e, `//`
- `g` ensures that matching is *global*, i.e., that *all* substrings that match the regex are replaced.

Result:

```
//Development/graphic/release/CM
//Development/graphic/release/GManager
//Development/graphic/release/Notification
//Development/graphic/release/Core
//Development/graphic/release/Provider
//Development/graphic/release/WH
//Development/graphic/release/Accessory
//Development/graphic/release/Unity Provider
//Development/graphic/release/tipManager
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I can't use -E option at sed cmd. I think this os is redhat

Comment: @user3754723: I see. I've just updated my answer to make it POSIX-compatible, which should work for you - let me know if it doesn't.

Comment: Thank you very much, and... I have one more question...:)

How can I store it to variable?

    list=`echo "$str" | sed 's# \(//\)#\'$'\n''\1#g'`

It doesn't work I want. I want to store it to list.

Comment: @user3754723 You're welcome; re capturing output in a variable: see my update.

Comment: Well, I still have to get same result :(

    `for element in $result
    do
        echo $element
    done`

Sorry, I can't comment beautyfully using new line :(

Comment: @user3754723: `for` is not the right tool for this (it splits on spaces, too, and has other pitfalls); use `while`: `while read -r path; do echo "$path"; done <<<"$result"`

Answer (score 0):

Use the Internal Field Separator (IFS) Variable to break on newline instead of white space.

This explains it well:
http://mindspill.net/computing/linux-notes/using-the-bash-ifs-variable-to-make-for-loops-split-with-non-whitespace-characters/

An example pulled from the link above:

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS=$','
vals='/mnt,/var/lib/vmware/Virtual Machines,/dev,/proc,/sys,/tmp,/usr/portage,/var/tmp'
for i in $vals; 
     do echo $i; 
done
unset IFS
```

Comment: Re terminology: Newlines are also a form of whitespace (white space). The OP's sample input is a _one-line_ string, so splitting by newlines does not apply.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this awk command also,

```
$ awk -v RS=" //" '{gsub (/^D/,"//D");}1' file
//Development/graphic/release/CM
//Development/graphic/release/GManager
//Development/graphic/release/Notification
//Development/graphic/release/Core
//Development/graphic/release/Provider
//Development/graphic/release/WH
//Development/graphic/release/Accessory
//Development/graphic/release/Unity Provider
//Development/graphic/release/tipManager
```

Comment: No No~ I want to do that like below:




//Development/graphic/release/CM
//Development/graphic/release/GManager
//Development/graphic/release/Notification
//Development/graphic/release/Core
//Development/graphic/release/Provider
//Development/graphic/release/WH
//Development/graphic/release/Accessory
//Development/graphic/release/Unity Provider
//Development/graphic/release/tipManager

Comment: post the above comment in your question.